# Как получить контент из другой страницы через php без изменения url?

Tags: php

Как получить контент из другой страницы через php без изменения url? Например так

```
if (function()) {
    ---
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    exit(file_get_contents('error.php'));
}
```

Но это код только для ошибки! Как сделать простой редирект на страниц

Comment: `Location: new_url.php` + HTTP 301/302 не?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev не знаю можно?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11307730/how-to-use-server-transfer-in-php

Comment: На всякий случай уточню: а что вы подразумеваете под "_без изменения url_"? Ведь URL и страница - это по-сути одно и тоже.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev как можно сказать мне нужно именно "без изменения url" потому что я проверяю id пользователя из баз данных если не существует то направляем на группу как вк.

Comment: ничего не понял

Comment: @DmitriySimushev - Похоже, что нужно, чтобы ответ приходил без изменения url в address-bar браузера - так, как работает Server.Transfer в ASP.NET, то есть без дополнительного запроса с новым адресом.

Comment: @Igor, ну значит речь идет не о редиректе а о замене содержимого страницы... но тогда я совсем не понимаю в чем проблема отдавать различный контент в зависимости от условий

Comment: @KYRAN, одно из двух: вам либо не нужен редирект (речь об отдаче разного контента в зависимости от каких-то условий), либо URL придется менять. Вы уж определитесь, что именно вы хотите получить!

Comment: @DmitriySimushev извините я обновил вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так, код, который вы привели для ошибки, сделайте тоже самое , только не нужно указывать `header` и вывести `exit(file_get_contents('content.php'));`

**UPDATE**
Для выполнения файла:

```
include 'content.php';
```

Comment: Попробовал направляется но php код не работает! http://postimg.org/image/o9wr3wvjj/

Comment: @KYRAN, и что? проблема-то в чем?! что именно не работает?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev это фото из исходный текст http://postimg.org/image/t8y2mvw2b/ и php файл бывает как комментарий

Comment: @K.. Вы отдаете содержимое PHP файла "как есть"? Серьезно?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev я исходил из того, что предоставил ТС, мало ли что у него там в PHP-файлах хранится, может просто HTML…

Comment: @KYRAN, так ваш код - просто содержимое файла отдает, если нужно выполнить код -`include 'content.php';`